# Windows XP identifies only one core

Tags: windows-xp, intel-core-i7

I am using a Dell Latitude 6410 laptop with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU M 620  @ 2.67GHz processor.
I am not sure how many core it supports, but I assume it should be minimum of 2. But Windows XP task manager seems to identify only one core. Why is that?

Comment: Which service pack are you using?  It might be that you need the latest service pack to support multicore processors...

Comment: I use Windows XP SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP Professional can support up to two processors regardless of the number of cores on the processor, Microsoft Windows XP Home supports one processor.  The OS sees a single CPU, it's up to the application to see the cores and then take advantage of multi-threading.

Comment: Does that mean I cannot see the usage of individual cores from task manager? But I thought I have seen it before. Also how to identify the number of cores in the processor?

Comment: Try Process Lasso, it should show the cores and their current usage: http://www.bitsum.com/prolasso.php